# Hard Lefschetz property and Moishezon manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Cohomology ring of a closed manifold $M^{2n}$ is said to satisfy **hard Lefschetz property** if there exists an element $a\in H^2(M,\mathbb R)$ such that multiplication by $a^k$ yields an isomorphism
$$H^{n-k}(M,\mathbb R)\to H^{n+k}(M,\mathbb R)$$
for all $k=1,\dots,n$.

By the hard Lefschetz theorem cohomology ring of any compact Kahler manifold $(M,\omega)$ has this property with $a=[\omega]$.

My question is: What are the examples of (necessarily non-Kahler) Moishezon (or Fujiki class C) manifolds with cohomology ring not satisfying hard Lefschetz property?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136049/three-dimensional-compact-k%C3%A4hler-manifolds. For almost Kahler manifolds, see http://www.archipel.uqam.ca/3755/1/D1973.pdf

Comment: The Lefschetz
property is equivalent to the $dδ$-lemma:
There is a paper, A New Construction of Symplectic Manifolds
Author(s): Robert E. Gompf
Source: Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 142, No. 3 (Nov., 1995), pp. 527-595

Comment: See Theorem 0.10, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0524.pdf

Comment: Thanks, Hassan. I was aware of these results, however I am specifically interested in Moishezon manifolds.

Comment: Could you explain what is a Moishezon manifold?

Comment: @JarekKędra: A Moishezon manifold is a compact complex manifold, say of dimension $n$, whose field of meromorphic functions is isomorphic to the field of meromorphic functions of a complex projective variety of dimension $n$, as field extensions of the complex numbers.

Comment: Theorem 1.1 of this preprint can give better definition in Kahler current language via positivity theory , called Demailly's characterization of Moishezon manifolds, http://www.mat.jhu.edu/~shiffman/publications/34%20closed%20positive%20currents%201993.pdf

Comment: It is not related to Moishezon manifolds, but I think it is nice result due to work of O.Gabber and others . Let $X$ be a smooth complex algebraic variety, together with a compactification $\bar X$ and an ample line bundle $L$ on $\bar X$. Then we have hard Lefschetz property  in intersection cohomology 
$$H^{\dim X-r}_c(X^{an},\mathbb C)→H^{\dim X+r}_c(X^{an},\mathbb C)$$
for $r\geq \dim C(\bar X−X)+1$ See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-322-86856-5_28

Comment: Your question is special case of  Grothendieck's standard conjectures 1968! .https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/StandardConjs.pdf

Comment: @HassanJolany Sorry, but I do not see how Grothedieck's paper is related to my question. He asks about hard Lefschetz for *projective* manifolds over   arbitrary algebraically closed field, while I am interested in *non-projective* manifolds over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: There are Moishezon manifolds which are not scheme, so  I don't know how hard Lefschetz property for non-scheme make sense. I think you have assumed smooth case. But I was not careful about my previous comment(you was right!). The question is still largely open that under which condition a Moishezon manifold(in singular setting) is scheme. see  D. LUNA, Toute variété de Moisezon presque homogène sous un tore est un schéma, C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris, 314, Série I, (1992), 65-67.

Comment: I asked your question from Frederic Campana:It seems your question is high level of research question:  This is his answer: Ce theoreme presuppose l'existence d'une polarisation (donc la projectivite de la variete) avec laquelle prendre les intersections (en cohomologie). Il est bien sur possible que l'on puisse en donner une version Moishezon (mais il faut alors savoir quoi prendre pour remplacer la polarisation). L'existence de courbes complexes homologues a zero sur certains exemples (tous?) montre qu'il y aura probablement des difficultes (au niveau des definitions deja) a surmonter.